# disorder on "tab" button in login form

Tags: c#, forms, button, authentication, tabs

I need help with a login form....I want to move from username to password and to login with the tab button from my keyboard but it goes from username to login and then to password and the to username and at least to login...!!!!

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SplashScreen
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            password_txt.PasswordChar='*';
            password_txt.MaxLength = 45;
        }




        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\SplashScreen\SplashScreen\armaos.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count (*) from [Table] where username='" + username_txt.Text + "' and password ='" + password_txt.Text +"'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                MainProg mp = new MainProg();
                mp.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Λανθασμένα Πεδία");
            }

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void username_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void password_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Login_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Use `TabIndex` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Forms designer, and choose `View->Tab order`. Then you can click on each of the controls in the sequence you want them to be when the user presses the tab key.

(Unsure whether the name is exact, my Visual Studio edition is not English).